# How can one keep react-hook-form forms isolated on dynamic routes in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hook-form

I am building a React web application which uses [react-hook-form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/) for form control and [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) for handling routing.

The issue is that I have a dynamic route which contains a form, and the forms on each page are sharing data when they should be logically isolated.

To try and solve the issue, I created this example app to illustrate the problem:

```
import './App.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, NavLink, Outlet, RouterProvider, useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <>
        <h1>Router Issue Example</h1>
        <nav>
          <NavLink to="forms/1">Pick Form 1</NavLink>
          <span>   |   </span>
          <NavLink to="forms/2">Pick Form 2</NavLink>
          <span>   |   </span>
          <NavLink to="forms/3">Pick Form 3</NavLink>
        </nav>
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'forms/:dynamicId',
        loader: DynamicFormPageLoader,
        element: <DynamicFormPage />
      }
    ]
  },
])

function DynamicFormPageLoader({params}: any) {
  const dynamicId = params.dynamicId
  return {dynamicId}
}

function DynamicFormPage() {
  const {dynamicId} = useLoaderData() as {dynamicId: string};
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm()
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Dynamic Form Page</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })}>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #1 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question1`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

In this example, if I go to forms/1 and submit some data in the form and then go to form 2 or 3, it will have that data in the form and when I submit the data, it will submit it as if it was all one form. The desired behavior is for each form to be entirely isolated from one another such that submitting data in one form only logs the data in the others.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: New Solution Found**

I ended up rooting out the core issue here and found a more seamless solution. Just add a `key` attribute to the `form` element of each `DynamicFormPage` element like so...

```
import './App.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, NavLink, Outlet, RouterProvider, useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <>
        <h1>Router Issue Example</h1>
        <nav>
          <NavLink to="forms/1">Pick Form 1</NavLink>
          <span>   |   </span>
          <NavLink to="forms/2">Pick Form 2</NavLink>
          <span>   |   </span>
          <NavLink to="forms/3">Pick Form 3</NavLink>
        </nav>
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'forms/:dynamicId',
        loader: DynamicFormPageLoader,
        element: <DynamicFormPage />
      }
    ]
  },
])

function DynamicFormPageLoader({params}: any) {
  const dynamicId = params.dynamicId
  return {dynamicId}
}

function DynamicFormPage() {
  const {dynamicId} = useLoaderData() as {dynamicId: string};
  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm()
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Dynamic Form Page</h2>
      <form 
      key={dynamicId} // <---- Add a key attribute 
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })}>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #1 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question1`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Turns out the issue was (mostly) unrelated to both [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main); it was just that React evaluates whether elements in the DOM are the "same" based on whether the same type of element is in the same spot. Because the dynamic route doesn't actually change the DOM structure, React considers them the same element and persists the state.

A better explanation of the root issue can be found [in this video by Web Dev Simplified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXJkeZf-4-4&t=253s&pp=ygUecmVhY3Qga2V5IG1vc3Qgc2VuaW9yIHdlYiBkZXZz)

Answer (score 0):

You could [reset](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset/) the form state when the `dynamicId` route parameter updates. Use the `useEffect` hook to "react" to the route param value updating.

```
function DynamicFormPage() {
  const { dynamicId } = useParams() as { dynamicId: string };
  const { handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(); // <-- pass any reset options, if necessary
  }, [dynamicId, reset]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Dynamic Form Page</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })}>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #1 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question1`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Form${dynamicId}-question #2 `}
          <input type="text" {...register(`${dynamicId}-question2`)} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I just tried it and it works, but it bothers me that now I have to have the state of the planning form disappear entirely whenever a user navigates away from and back to the page. Do you happen to know of any solution that would allow the state of each form to stay between navigation?

Comment: @NateRardin I see, so these are not totally independent forms/states, but are related in some way. One solution I can think of is to use a "global" form "state" (e.g. React Context or Redux) that holds the individual form field values, and depending which form is "loaded" pass the data as the form's initial data. Does this make sense? I'm not very familiar with `react-hook-form`, but a quick check in the docs for anything "multi-step" form related I found [this](https://www.react-hook-form.com/faqs/#Howtoworkwithmodalortabforms) which appears to suggest a similar solution using a global state.

Comment: Funnily enough I tried to make an edit to my original comment saying I was thinking about trying that as a solution but couldn't due to the 5 min edit rule. Definitely seems like the way to go. Thanks!